How to handle paste image from clipboard when you have multiple image upload fields on the same page?
I'm maintaining an old vuejs 2 application, done by someone else who left the company. This is our only vuejs app so no one knows vue that much and wondering if you could help. I wrote the following code I'm asking about though.
We have boostrap 2 columns, a left column and a right column, inside each of those columns there's a textarea and an image upload field, so in total you have 2 textarea and 2 image upload fields.
You can upload by clicking the browse button or by drag and drop or by pasting the image directly from the clipboard, we're using Filepond to handle the upload mechanism. We allow only 1 image per image input field.
The issue I'm reporting is only with regard to pasting the image directly from the clipboard, so basically, when you paste an image, both image inputs will receive the same image. What I want is that when the user pastes an image from clipboard, then  the image upload field where his mouse is hovering over should be filled. So if you're hovering over the left column and paste an image then only the left image input field should have the image you pasted.
<div class="row">

            <!-- Notes Section -->
            <div class="col-6">
                <label for="notes">Report</label>
                <textarea id="notes"
                            class="form-control"
                            rows="10"
                            v-model="pmNotes"></textarea>

                <label class="mt-2">Upload Image</label>
                <file-pond ref="notesFilePond"
                            name="notesImage"
                            label-idle="Drag & Drop your image or <span class='filepond--label-action'>Browse</span>"
                            accepted-file-types="image/*"
                            :files="notesImages"
                            @updatefiles="handleNotesFilesUpdate"
                            @init="handleNotesFilePondInit"></file-pond>
            </div>

            <!-- Planned Tasks Section -->
            <div class="col-6">
                <label for="plannedTasks">Plan</label>
                <textarea id="plannedTasks"
                            class="form-control"
                            rows="8"
                            v-model="plannedTasks"></textarea>

                <label class="mt-2">Upload Image</label>
                <file-pond ref="plannedTasksFilePond"
                            name="plannedTasksImage"
                            label-idle="Drag & Drop your image or <span class='filepond--label-action'>Browse</span>"
                            accepted-file-types="image/*"
                            :files="plannedTasksImages"
                            @updatefiles="handlePlannedTasksFilesUpdate"
                            @init="handlePlannedTasksFilePondInit"></file-pond>
            </div>
</div>
import vueFilePond from 'vue-filepond';
// Import FilePond plugins
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation';
import FilePondPluginImageValidateSize from 'filepond-plugin-image-validate-size';

// Import FilePond styles
import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css';

// Create FilePond component
const FilePond = vueFilePond(
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
    FilePondPluginImageValidateSize
);

export default {
    name: 'CreateDailyReport',

    components: {
        FilePond
    }
    ...

    method

        handleNotesFilePondInit() {
            this.$refs.notesFilePond.setOptions({
                allowPaste: true,
                pasteOnPage: false,
                pasteTarget: this.$refs.notesFilePond.$el, // Ensures only this element handles paste
                allowMultiple: false,
                maxFiles: 1,
            });
        },
        handlePlannedTasksFilePondInit() {
            this.$refs.plannedTasksFilePond.setOptions({
                allowPaste: true,
                pasteOnPage: false,
                pasteTarget: this.$refs.plannedTasksFilePond.$el, // Ensures only this element handles paste
                allowMultiple: false,
                maxFiles: 1,
            });
        },


You would need to track the hover state of each element and update the FilePond options whenever that state changed.  Only enable the paste options when hovered and disable when not.
Forgive me if the syntax isn't perfect.  It's been awhile since I've worked in this framework, but the concept should work.
You need to add two boolean variables to your component:
data() {
    return {
      isNotesFilePondHovered: false, 
      isTasksFilePondHovered: false,  
    };
}

Add two functions to your component that update the FilePond options (they'd both look similar to this one):
handleNotesFilePondUpdate() {
            this.$refs.notesFilePond.setOptions({
                allowPaste: this.isNotesFilePondHovered,
                pasteOnPage: false,
                pasteTarget: this.isNotesFilePondHovered ? this.$refs.notesFilePond.$el : null
            });
        },

In the component watch for changes to the hovered variables and call the proper function when a change is detected:
watch: {
    isNotesFilePondHovered(newValue) {
      // React to the hover state change of the first element
      this.handleNotesFilePondUpdate();
    },
    isTasksFilePondHovered(newValue) {
      // React to the hover state change of the second element
      this.handleTasksFilePondUdpate();
    },
  },

Add mouse in and out events to both FilePond elements in the template that update the hovered variables in the component:
<file-pond ref="notesFilePond"
                            name="notesImage"
                            label-idle="Drag & Drop your image or <span class='filepond--label-action'>Browse</span>"
                            accepted-file-types="image/*"
                            :files="notesImages"
                            @updatefiles="handleNotesFilesUpdate"
                            @init="handleNotesFilePondInit"
                            @mouseenter="isNotesFilePondHovered = true"
                            @mouseleave="isNotesFilePondHovered = false"></file-pond>

There are edge cases to consider, like the initialization of an element that is already hovered wouldn't have a @mouseenter event triggered.  You also may not like that an element must be hovered to paste and want to default to one or the other.
